# How can I change volume from volume preference on android?

Tags: android, volume, preference, ringtone

I have an app has volume preference, below my layout code:

```
<VolumePreference
android:name="Volume Preference"
android:summary="Ringtone Volume"
android:title="Ringtone Volume"
android:key="ringVolPref"/>
```

But I don't know, How to implement that on class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

**XML**

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="100"
android:minWidth="250px"  />
```

**CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will implement at preference activity to control notification volume, can u help me?

Comment: ok Dewa Yudie, try this method, if you then unable to accomplish this task then you can again ask problem on here, I will then help you...

Comment: I've tried that method mohsin.mr, but I cannot complete.. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, best way is to add to your .xml   `android:streamType`. This will change the volume of the selected stream type.

```
<VolumePreference
           android:title="Alarm volume"
           android:persistent="false"
           android:streamType="alarm"/>
```